TikZ chain placement of nodes with distance next to another one
In the following LaTeX source
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0mm and 10mm,
    font=\sffamily
  ]
  \tikzset{N/.style={draw, fill=green!20}}
  %% registers
  \begin{scope}[start chain=R going below,
    nodes={on chain=R},
    minimum width={width("R66")+2pt}
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {R\r};
    }
  \end{scope}
  %% data
  \begin{scope}[start chain=D going below, right=80mm of R-1.east,
    nodes={on chain=D},
    minimum width={width("Data 42")+2pt}
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {Data \r};
    }
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (D-1.north west) {\footnotesize MSB};
  \node[above] at (D-1.north east) {\footnotesize LSB};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I try to place the chain 'D' right of the chain 'R'. This results into

The intention is to place both scopes next to each other, starting at the same height with 1mm horizontal distance from each other. But even the 80mm set here seems to have no effect.
I have the two scopes because the formatting will later be different via macro with arguments for TikZ's pgfkeys/styles (using \r as arg) and thus the nodes should also be treated differently.

With first chain anchor=east and the second chain with anchor=west.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % node distance=0mm and 10mm,
    node distance=0mm,
    font=\sffamily
]
\tikzset{N/.style={draw, fill=green!20,inner sep=1pt}}
%% registers
\begin{scope}[start chain=R going below,
    nodes={on chain=R},
    minimum width={width("R66")},
    anchor=east%<--- added
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {R\r};
    }
\end{scope}
%% data
\begin{scope}[start chain=D going below, 
    anchor=west,%<--- added
    xshift=2pt,
    nodes={on chain=D},
    minimum width={width("Data 42")}
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {Data \r};
    }
\end{scope}
\node[above] at (D-1.north west) {\footnotesize MSB};
\node[above] at (D-1.north east) {\footnotesize LSB};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Something like this?
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0mm and 10mm,
    font=\sffamily
  ]
  \tikzset{N/.style={draw, fill=green!20}}
  %% registers
  \begin{scope}[start chain=R going below,
    nodes={on chain=R},
    minimum width={width("R66")+2pt}
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {R\r};
    }
  \end{scope}
  %% data
  \begin{scope}[start chain=D going below, at={(R-1.east)}, xshift=10mm,
    nodes={on chain=D},
    minimum width={width("Data 42")+2pt}
    ]%
    \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
        \node[N] {Data \r};
    }
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (D-1.north west) {\footnotesize MSB};
  \node[above] at (D-1.north east) {\footnotesize LSB};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you. Yes, something like that. But if I change the minimum width of one or both blocks, I have to adjust the xshift each time. I had hoped for more automatism, since LaTeX knows how wide something is and so the 1mm to the next block (at least from my point of view) is easy to realize ;-)

But the question remains for me: Why doesn't have start chain=D going below, right=80mm of R-1.east, not the effect as intended?

@olStckEx The right=80mm of R-1.east in the scope options for the D chain specifies the distance from the east anchor of the node R-1 to the west anchor of the first node in the D chain. However, the right=80mm option alone does not ensure that the chains will be properly aligned vertically.

That is already very good, thank you again. But why is the horizontal alignment of the nodes in a row not maintained if, for example, I write \node[N] {R\r\,(X\r)}; in one of the R chains? The minimum height is not maintained, even if I enter the same height for both chains as (minimum height={height(“R66 (XX)”)+2pt}); source currently looks with your help: https://cocalc.com/share/public_paths/d88c32020c6f2a78c74858fbeee4e234b5ff4ebf

@olStckEx I think that the issue you're experiencing with horizontal alignment of nodes in your chains likely arises from the fact that the content of the nodes is not the same, causing different heights for the nodes. This discrepancy can be addressed by setting a uniform height for all nodes to ensure consistent alignment.
